# Event Handler Called With Wrong Context

Tags: javascript, dom-events

In the `SomeObj` object, the `onkeydown` event handler `this.doSomething` is called in the wrong context (that of the textbox element) but it needs to be called in the context of `this`. How can this be done?

```
function SomeObj(elem1, elem2) {
    this.textboxElem = elem1;
    this.someElem = elem2;
    this.registerEvent();
}

SomeObj.prototype = {
    registerEvent: function() {
        this.textboxElem.onkeydown = this.doSomething;
    },
    doSomething: function() {
        // this must not be textboxElem
        alert(this);
        this.someElem.innerHTML = "123";
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy the reference to a local variable, so that you can use it in a closure:

```
registerEvent: function() {
  var t = this;
  this.textboxElem.onkeydown = function() {
    t.doSomething();
  };
},
```