# Accessing a class property in a callback function

Tags: javascript

I got a little problem in my code. Here it is :

```
// We are in the constructor of my class
this.socket.emit('getmap', {name: name}, function(data){
    this.mapData = data.map;
    this.load();
});
```

The problem is that the `mapData` attribute isn't set, in fact, `this` refers to the namespace Socket. **How can I access to `this.mapData` through this function ?**

And sorry for my bad english ...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Event Handler Called With Wrong Context](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6300817/event-handler-called-with-wrong-context)

Comment: @palra would you mark one of the answers as "correct" please?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to save a reference to the `this` object. Inside the callback `this`will refer to the object on which the function has been called. A common pattern is this:

```
// We are in the constructor of my class
var self = this;
this.socket.emit('getmap', {name: name}, function(data){
    self.mapData = data.map;
    self.load();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to be aware of how JavaScript determines the value of `this`. In anonymous functions like the one you're using, it's usually the global namespace or `window` object on the web. In any case, I would just suggest you take advantage of the closure and use a variable in your constructor.

```
// We are in the constructor of my class
var _this = this;
this.socket.emit('getmap', {name: name}, function(data){
    _this.mapData = data.map;
    _this.load();
});
```

Comment: @palra I recommend reading up on the `this` keyword in javascript in general. E.g. http://devign.me/javascript-this-keyword/. Google "javascript this keyword" and you'll find many explanations.